# Multiple form select from drop down menu

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two forms: form1 and form2 and a drop down.

I want to appear a particular form as I select any form name from drop down.

Comment: please show what you tried

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/change/ , http://api.jquery.com/hide/ , http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 0):

```
function onDropDownChange() {
    if (document.getElementById("drop-down-id").value === 1) {
        document.getElementById('form1').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('form2').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('form2').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('form1').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

or if you want to use jquery,

```
 $("#drop-down-id").change(function(){
          if ($(this).val() == "Type1") {
                $('.form1').hide('');
                $('.form2').show('');
          }
         else {
                $('.form2').show('');
                $('.form1').hide('');
          }
});
```